# If $t^p-(r^p+s^p) \equiv 0 (\mod p)$ implies $t-(r+s)=pq$, do other solutions exist for relatively prime $r$, $s$ and $t$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If
$$t^p-(r^p+s^p) \equiv 0 \;( \text{mod}\; p) \tag{1}$$ 
where $r$, $s$ and $t$ are all relatively prime non-zero positive integers and $p$ is any odd prime.

then one solution super set, that includes at least some of the relatively prime solutions is $$t-(r+s)=pq \tag{2}$$, where $q$ is a positive integer.

I think the most straight forward way to prove this is to assume (2) correct and write

$$t^p-(t-pq)^p+(r+s)^p-(r^p+s^p)$$

and to then separately confirm that
$$t^p-(t-pq)^p \equiv 0 \;( \text{mod}\; p) \tag{3}$$

$$(r+s)^p-(r^p+s^p) \equiv 0 \;( \text{mod}\; p) \tag{4}$$

(3) being an obvious result and (4) being a well known result.

The question is are there other relatively prime solutions to (1) outside of those encompassed by (2)?

Answer (score 1):

No. The most simple way to see this is to work in the field $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Indeed, in this field, the *Frobenius map*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\\
x&\longmapsto x^p
\end{align}
is a ring homomorphism, i.e. for any $x,y\in\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, $\;(x+y)^p\equiv x^p+y^p$ (this results from the binomial formula and the fact that, if $p$ is prime, $\;\binom pk\equiv 0\bmod p$ for all $1\le k\le p-1$) and $(xy)^p\equiv x^py^p$.

Therefor, one has 
$\;t^p-(r^p+s^p)\equiv \bigl(t-(r+s)\bigr)^p$, and as we're in a field,
$$\bigl(t-(r+s)\bigr)^p\equiv 0\iff t-(r+s)\equiv 0\pmod p$$

*Note*: this has nothing to do with $r,s,t$ being relatively prime.

Comment: What does $\bmod (p,t)$ mean in this context?

Comment: Sorry Bernard have now deleted my previous comments; Not being a natural mathematician I very easily confuse myself when I think ahead about the next step.